# How to calculate percentage of mising data in a time series in R dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, time-series

In the following sample data and script,
How can I calculate the % of missing data between start date `strtdt` and end date `enddt` for each ID. What I want to get is: add the missing days with `NA` between `strtdt` and `enddt` separately for each IDs than calculated the % of NA. 
I tried following using dplyr but for no luck. Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.
Note: I can achieve same by calculating individually for each ID however that is not possible because I have more than 10000 IDs.
Ultimate goal is to get % of `NA` between start date and end date for each ID; If the dates are missing completely than i have to add missing date with `NA` values.

```
    library(dplyr


    df<-structure(list(ID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L
), .Label = c("xx", "xyz", "yy", "zz"), class = "factor"), Date = structure(c(8L, 
9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L), .Label = c("1989-09-12", 
"1989-09-13", "1989-09-14", "1989-09-19", "1989-09-23", "1990-01-12", 
"1990-01-13", "1996-09-12", "1996-09-13", "1996-09-16", "1996-09-17", 
"1996-09-18", "1996-09-19", "2000-09-12", "2000-09-13", "2000-11-10", 
"2000-11-11", "2000-11-12", "2001-09-07", "2001-09-08", "2001-09-09", 
"2001-09-10", "2001-09-11"), class = "factor"), val = c(3, 5, 
9, 3, 5, 6, 8, 7, 9, 5, 3, 2, 8, 8, 5, 3, 2, 1, 5, 7, NA, NA, 
NA, NA)), .Names = c("ID", "Date", "val"), row.names = c(NA, 
-24L), class = "data.frame") 

df$Date<-as.Date(df$Date,format="%Y-%m-%d")
df
df_mis<-df %>%
  group_by(ID)%>%
  dplyr::mutate(strtdt=min(Date),
                enddt=max(Date))
df_mis

df_mis2<-df_mis %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  dplyr::do( data.frame(., Date1= seq(.$strtdt,.$enddt, by = '1 day')))
df_mis2
```

Comment: The dates in your example data frame are factors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume from the sequence generation in the question's code, that the expected observations are one per day between the first observed date and last observed date per ID.  Here's a clunky piece by piece calculation to count the % missing data.

#### 1. Make a data frame of all expected dates for each ID

```
library(dplyr)
# df as in the question, but coerce Date column
df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date)

# Data frame with date ranges per id
ranges_df <- df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarize(min=min(Date), max=max(Date))

# Data frame with IDs and date for every day expected. 
alldays <- ranges_df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  do(., data.frame( 
          Date = seq(.$dmin,.$dmax, by = '1 day')
        )
  )
```

#### 2. JOIN the expected dates table with the observed dates table.

```
imputed_df <- left_join(alldays, df)
```

#### 3. Count NAs

```
imputed_df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  summarize(total=n(), 
            missing=sum(is.na(val)), 
            percent_missing=missing/total*100 
  )
```

#### result:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 4
      ID total missing percent_missing
  <fctr> <int>   <int>           <dbl>
1     xx     8       2        25.00000
2    xyz     4       4       100.00000
3     yy    62      57        91.93548
4     zz  4380    4371        99.794
```

Assuming that NAs in the original data should be counted as missing data, this will do so.

Comment: The gist is here: https://gist.github.com/grosscol/09ca5a4e48f1adfe4968c4d4a7652ee5

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the number of days between the min and max of dates as an intermediate variable.

Then, calculate the number of missing days as number of days - number of observations. Then, calculate percentages.

```
df %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    mutate(numdays = as.numeric(max(Date) - min(Date)) + 1,
        pctmissing = (numdays - n()) / numdays)
```

Comment: @LilyNature your example data did not include NAs

Comment: @ColinGross Gross i have updated the data to reflect real scenario with NAs.